# Replacement for active x object

Tags: javascript, vba, outlook

I am working on developing Outlook appointment. I have a requirement where
I have to create a file and download it . When I open that file it has to  open in outlook and create meeting request pop up without using active x . Is there any api developed by Microsoft. Its better if the snippet is from java script

Right now I am able to open pop up with Meeting request in Outlook from the web browser. I am able to do this by enabling Active x controls But it works in IE only. Moreover active x will not be supported by Microsoft in near future.

Current code

```
var outlookAppObj = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");

var objNS = outlookAppObj.GetNameSpace("MAPI");

var theMailItemObj 

=outlookAppObj.CreateItem(0);

theMailItemObj.display();
```

Comment: Have you looked here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: Microsoft outlook client I am using is 2010. But here it supports from 2013.https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets

Comment: @dmitry-streblechenko could you please into this

Answer (score 0):

Your code above creates and displays a regular message. You can achieve the same result using a `mailto:` link.

For an appointment, create an ICS file and the user download it - Outlook will be happy to open it. the user can then click Save.

Answer (score 0):

```
Prepare ics file as var finalAttachedData =  "ATTACH;FMTTYE= application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=test.docx:"+base+"\n";         
var icsMSG = ["BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\n" + finalAttachedData + "\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::testmail\nDTSTART:" + Date.now() +"\nDTEND:" + Date.now() +"\nLOCATION:" + "hyd" + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR"];
```

Comment: base is the data read as byte array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060543/5588679