# How to read external docx file content using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, docx

The following is the request formed:

Request URL: https://remoteserverurl.docx
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.232.4.216:7317
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: isPageflowTouch=true; schemaId=1; updCtx=true; typeId=91433788276151561974313054830
Host: domain.test.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36

Comment: @dmitry-streblechenko could you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
function getdocx(url){
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var arrayBuffer;
oReq.open('GET', url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
   var binary = '';
   var bytes = new Uint8Array( arrayBuffer );
   var len = bytes.byteLength;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
 }
var contentfromDocx = window.btoa( binary );
//do what ever you want with this
oReq.send(null);
```

}